# How can I make AirFoil detect the speaker without rebooting the Mac?

Tags: applications, airport, streaming

When my Mac goes to sleep, and I awake it, AirFoil no longer detects my Airport Expert speakers.

I always need to restart OS X to make AirFoil detect it; restarting AirFoil doesn't fix it.

Do you know how could I avoid this?

Comment: Isn't there somewhere a setting to activate the "start on login"-option? I'm not sure ('cause I'm not on my Mac right now), but I can check when I come home. I'm quite sure there is somewhere a setting to solve this problem!

Comment: @Michiel Not sure I've understood your comment. What's going to change if Airfoil starts at login ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but does Airfoil have a Helper application running in the background? Maybe you have to quit that one as well instead of just restarting AirFoil?

Also, do you have the latest version? I have just checked and the Release Notes on the Rogue Amoeba website have a bugfix in the latest release 4.6.2 from a few weeks ago that seems to match your problem:

http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/releasenotes.php

> Airfoil now disconnects from remote speakers upon sleeping, to prevent error messages on waking.

Maybe that update can solve your problem?